# What is the precedence of the + (plus) operator in Java?

Tags: java

The precedence for the plus operator is listed only once in the [java tutorial precedence table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).  However the following Java expressions:

```
String unexpected = "1 + 1 = " + 1 + 1; 
String expected   = "1 + 1 = " + (1 + 1);
System.out.println(unexpected);
System.out.println(expected);
```

result in this output:

```
1 + 1 = 11
1 + 1 = 2
```

Does this mean the plus operator has a higher precedence when used to concatenate Strings, or does it mean the plus operator's precedence is no different for Strings and Numbers, but that it is simply evaluated left to right?

Comment: Why should it differ? All string concatenations are compiled with StringBuilder. So this has nothing to do with evaluation, but rather with compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` always flow from *left to right*

in your first example `String unexpected = "1 + 1 = " + 1 + 1;` , string comes first and then the int value so 1 is treated as string.

in your second example `String expected   = "1 + 1 = " + (1 + 1);` , you are using `()` which is having higher precedence over + operator.(**BODMAS**)

**consider another example:**

```
String unexpected1 =1+1+ "1 + 1 = " ;
 System.out.println(unexpected1);
```

output will be `21 + 1 =`

here int value comes first so 1+1 =2 and then the string literal so 2 is concatenated with 1+1=

Answer (score 8):

It means it is [evaluated left to right](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.1).

Answer (score 2):

[**From jls SE8 15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator +:**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) The `+`  operator  is  syntactically  *left-associative*,  no  matter  whether  it  is  determined  by
type analysis to represent string concatenation or numeric addition. In some cases care is
required to get the desired result. For example, the expression:

```
a + b + c
```

is always regarded as meaning: `(a + b) + c`

Therefore the result of the expression: `1 + 2 + " fiddlers"`

is: `"3 fiddlers"`

but the result of: `"fiddlers " + 1 + 2`

is: `"fiddlers 12"`

Another example: `1 + 1 + "" + 1 + 1` 

will result in : `211`

That is why, for your context `"1 + 1 = " + 1 + 1;`

 will result in string `1 + 1 = 11`

But, `"1 + 1 = " + (1 + 1);` will result in `1 + 1 = 2`

Answer (score 0):

Using + in strings will trigger a concatenation rather than summation.
But when you use (1+1) and sum it to "1+1=" using a +, the expression inside the parentheses will be evaluated first then concatenated to the rest of the string. Evaluating the inside of the parentheses works independently from the String, thus 1 and 1 will be considered two integers being added to each other.

And when using same operators, everything is evaluated from left to right.
There is an order of evaluation for operators that you can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)